# How to get Anypoint Platform access token?

Tags: mule, bearer-token, anypoint-platform

I need access token of my anypoint platform which is deployed on on-prem servers and have platinum subscription. So, able to access things in Anypoint Platform as well. I mean, it is an Hybrid model. It is working fine with my trial account when i hit the below URL with  my trail account creds.
https://anypoint.mulesoft.com:443/accounts/login getting below response

```
{
"access_token": "9123-4e33-84df-abc124",
"token_type": "bearer",
"redirectUrl": "/home/"
}
```

but when i try with my client creds getting below response instead of access token in body.

```
 {
"url": "https://verify.salesforce.com/verify/",
"body": {
    "request": "eyJhFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6Imp3dCIsImtpZCI6ImFueXBvaW50X2lhbV9wcm9kLWMyYy02NS0xNjYxNzMxMjI0Mjk5IiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIn0.eyJzdHkiOiJUZW5InRydXN0X3ZlcmlmaWVkX2RldmljZXMiOmZhbHNlLCJlbWFpbCI6IlNUaGlydXBhdGhpQEtDU291dGhlcm4uY29tIiw-E_-N4q4hBBkMq5NQ"
}
}
```

Comment: When you say you have "deployed" anypoint platform on-prem, do you mean you are using the [Anypoint Platform Private Cloud Edition](https://docs.mulesoft.com/private-cloud/3.1/) and have installed the on premise edition of anypoint platform in your server?

Comment: It is Hybrid Model

Comment: Is the organization using external identity? https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/external-identity-index

Comment: seems it is salesforce, that is why sending response url https://verify.salesforce.com/verify/

Comment: Hybrid deployment is not relevant because the issue is to get the access token, not what you will do with the token after.

Answer (score 1):

If the Anypoint Platform organization uses External Identity you can not use the login API because the login actually happens in your company Identity Provider (IdP). Usually the token is needed for automated access to APIs. You have two options:

1. *(not recommended)* Get a bearer token from the IdP of your organization. You'll need to reach out to your organization administrator to learn if you are allowed to do that and how. It really depends on the implementation of the IdP.
2. *(recommended)* Create a [Connected App](https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/connected-apps-overview) for the access that you need and then [get a bearer token for the connected app](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Creating-connected-app-and-getting-the-bearer-token-example).